# Why is the While statement is executing only 1 time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I just started programming and I was challenged to implement multiplication through addition. Here is my code.

```
def multiply(a,b):
    c=0
    while a!=0 and b!=0:
        a=(abs(a)-1)
        c=b+b
    return print(c)

multiply(5,3)
```

The problem is that it's giving me the answer 6. I think that the "while" statement is executing only 1 time. Why is that?

Comment: It is trivial to add print statements to the `while` loop to determine how many times it executes, which will help you determine where the problem actually lies.

Comment: @chepner Or learn to use pdb.

Comment: @Kupiakos I think it's pretty evident he's a beginner. Though your advice is in his best interests, it is better to guide him towards developing basic debugging skills using print statements than recommending him something like a full fledged debugger.

Comment: you should simply `return c` in your def and then `print multiply(5,3)`.  This would allow `c` to be used as an input later on.

Answer (score 4):

Because `c=b+b` replaces the value of `c` each time through the loop, no matter how many times the loop runs.  Try `c=c+b` instead.